# python nose tests: specifying which node the test should be run in Selenium Grid

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, nose

I am trying to update my **Selenium Grid Hub** capable tests to run via the **nose tests** framework.

Currently, without nosetests, if I wanted to start a process and have it run against a specific node I'd add this type of code in the SelRunner.py file

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen('python Tst_Ayusa_Nmo.py 5564 WINDOWS chrome')
```

This would then pass the system parameters of 5564 WINDOWS chrome into my test file, and it will know which Grid node it should be executing.

```
#execute test on this node: 5564 WINDOWS chrome
def setUp(self):
        if len(sys.argv) > 1:
            args = sys.argv
            port = args[1]
            platform = args[2]
            browser = args[3]
```

Now I've looked at various posts here about nose, but I am not quite sure how I can accomplish the same thing below:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    argv = ['--with-xunit', 'Tst_Ayusa_Nmo.py 5564']
    nose.main(argv=argv)
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'py 5564')
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\loader.py", line 402, in loadTestsFromName
    module = resolve_name(addr.module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\util.py", line 321, in resolve_name
    obj = getattr(obj, part)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'py 5564'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Thanks so much as always!

P.S. I am open to other methods of passing in the node configuration besides the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use TestConfig plugin. So I launch nose tests like the following:

```
nose.run(argv=['nosetests','-v','-s','--with-xunit','--tc-file','./configFile'], 
             plugins=[TestConfig(),Capture(),Xunit()])
```

and inside test I do

```
from testconfig import config
import sys
class testModule_1:
    def test_M1_1(self):
        print 'Module 1 Test 1 Config: ' + config['rc_configuration']['command']
```

And example of my config file:

```
[TEST_CONFIG]
xunitFile = firefoxTests.xml

[rc_configuration]
command = GoogleChrome
```

'

Comment: Great, that worked. To elaborate, your config file is where you'd put the port number and etc. eg:  [TEST_CONFIG]
xunitFile = android_ANDROID_5554.xml

[rc_configuration]
browser = android
platform = ANDROID
node = 8080
hostport = 8080